# Builder pattern not adding values to the object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, builder-pattern

I am attempting to follow the [ES6 Builder pattern](https://github.com/FelipeBB/Design-Patterns-JS/blob/master/docs.md#builder), as I am now starting to construct a more complex object.

So far I have:

```
class Opinion {
  constructor () {
    this.nuts = '';
  }
}

class Builder {
  constructor () {
    this.opinion = new Opinion();
  }

  withNuts (nuts) {
    this.nuts = nuts;
    return this;
  }

  build () {
    return this.opinion;
  }
}

export default Builder;
```

Which is used:

```
import Builder from '../helpers/builder/opinion';
const defaultOpinion = new Builder()
    .withNuts(2.9)
    .build();
```

That outputs:

```
opinion: {"nuts":""}
```

Why is it not being built into the object?

Also, when I want to pass an object back into the Builder, to be edited, it also returns blank (which makes sense), but would my current Builder set up allow this? For example:

```
 const opinionChange = new Builder(defaultOpinion)
    .withNuts(0.8)
    .build();
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You never use the `.nuts` of the builder anywhere? Where did you expect them to end up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to assign to the `this.opinion.nuts`, instead you create an own property `nuts` on the object. Replace with this

```
withNuts (nuts) {
    this.opinion.nuts = nuts;
    return this;
}
```

**Working Code**

```js
class Opinion {
  constructor () {
    this.nuts = '';
  }
}

class Builder {
  constructor () {
    this.opinion = new Opinion();
  }

  withNuts (nuts) {
    this.opinion.nuts = nuts; // this.opinion.nuts
    return this;
  }

  build () {
    return this.opinion;
  }
}


const defaultOpinion = new Builder()
    .withNuts(2.9)
    .build();
    
console.log(defaultOpinion);
```

Comment: Thank you, all values are returned! Would it be easy enough to change the builder to allow an object to be passed in and changed? Like this for example: ```const opinionChange = new Builder(defaultOpinion)
    .withNuts(0.8)
    .build();```

Comment: It also an approach, you need to change 2 constructors

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction please? How could I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Make the `constructor ()` to take an parameter, same for the `Opinion` and when you call `new Opinion()`, pass the parameter

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Like this: ```class Builder {
  constructor (build) {
    this.opinion = new Opinion(build);
  }``` and ```class Opinion {
  constructor (build) {
    this.nuts = build.nuts;
  }
}``` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `withNuts` method should update `this.opinion.nuts` instead of `this.nuts`:

```
withNuts (nuts) {
    this.opinion.nuts = nuts;
    return this;
}
```